# Ошибка в алгоритме нахождения коэффициента корреляции Пирсона

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Написал следующий код на c++ для нахождения коэффициента корреляции между двумя численными векторами с любым типом чисел. В результате выполнения для идентичных последовательностей получаю 1. Для теста, приведенного в коде получил значение, превышающее 1, хотя коэф. должен находиться в диапазоне от -1 до 1.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

template<typename num>
float corrcoef(vector<num> arr1, vector<num> arr2)
{
    if (arr1.size() != arr2.size()) {
        throw invalid_argument("Vectors must have simular length");
    }
    int size = arr1.size();
    int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0, sum12 = 0;
    int pow2sum1 = 0, pow2sum2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum1 += arr1[i]; sum2 += arr2[i];
        sum12 += arr1[i] * arr2[i];
        pow2sum1 += pow(arr1[i], 2);
        pow2sum2 += pow(arr2[i], 2);
    }

    return (size * sum12 - sum1 * sum2) / sqrt((size * pow2sum1 - pow(sum1, 2)) * (size * pow2sum2 - pow(sum2, 2)));
}

int main()
{
    vector<float> a = { 0.5, 1, 1.5 };
    vector<float> b = { 1, 3, 5 };
    cout << corrcoef(a, b);
}
```

В чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша ошибка  в использовании типа `int` там, где нужен тип с плавающей точкой.

```
double sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0, sum12 = 0;
double pow2sum1 = 0, pow2sum2 = 0;
```

Comment: Точно, ошибка элементарная. Замыленным взглядом не увидел. Спасибо

Comment: По идее же функция возвращает float, поэтому эти переменные тоже можно объявить с одинарной точностью

Comment: Можно, только вот лучше всегда использовать `double`, если нет каких-то особых причин (нужна какая-то особая экономия памяти) использовать `float`.

Comment: А нет ли разницы в перфомансе? Просто мне нужно 2 больших массива обрабатывать довольно быстро. Возможно я сейчас говорю ерунду (у меня с python осталась привычка все ускорять).

Comment: Как говорил товарищ Кнут, "все беды от преждевременной оптимизации". Добавим к этому, что программирование — наука экспериментальная. Попробуйте и так, и так (всей разницы — заменить одно слово), замерьте время, подумайте. Это в том случае, если алгоритмически ничего не удастся улучшить (это самый большой ресурс оптимизации — хороший алгоритм :)) Затем профилированием надо поискать узкие в смысле производительности места, и начинать с них.

Comment: См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1505511/195342 — вы меня сподвигли немного пемерить :)

Comment: Интересно что на Питоне с Нампи критерий Пирсона будет посчитан быстрее чем на C++.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну, давайте попробуем сравнить. Может, вопрос в реализации, в том, как именно считается на С++? :)