# Сравнение эффективности float и double

Tags: c++, c, оптимизация, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Сегодня в обычном вопросе в комментариях в очередной раз всплыл вопрос, использовать ли `float` или `double`; мотивация при этом была та же, что возникала уже не раз: `float` должен работать быстрее.

Насколько это и в самом деле так? Стоит ли повышение скорости снижения точности?

Comment: Cами вычисления происходят в 80 разрядных регистрах и должны работать одинаково float и double, разница будет при обращении к памяти

Comment: @PavelGridin, 80 разрядов - это про сопроцессор 8087 и его потомков. Уже давно архитектура сменилась и вычисления делаются по-другому.

Comment: Ошибки нормально никто не умеет контролировать. Поэтому всегда `double`. Исключения - итеративные методы (которые сами "чинят" ошибки), большие массивы (не лезет матрица в память). Если памяти хватает, то всегда `double`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ставлю вычислительный эксперимент. Вычисление интеграла методом Симпсона с заранее недостижимой точностью, просто чтоб выполнить одинаковое количество вычислений. Специально не матрицы, чтобы всякие эффекты вроде размещения в кэше не играли особой роли. Код просто пережевывает значения с плавающей точкой; приведен ниже.

Компиляция VC++2022, опции командной строки, связанные с оптимизацией — `/O2 /Ot /Oi /Ox /Oy /Ob2`.

При компиляции в 64-разрадное приложение среднее (по пяти выполнениям) время выполнения на моей машине 2.35 с для `float`, 2.84 с для `double`. Получается, для стандартных, так сказать, настроек `double` на 20% медленнее.

Если использовать ключ `/fp:fast`, о котором говорится дословно *результаты менее предсказуемы*, то получим 0.65 с и 1.55 с (медленнее в 2.4 раза).

В случае 32-разрядного приложения разница — 3.90 с для `float` и 5.93 с для `double`, т.е. разница 50% (в полтора раза) и для `/fp:fast` 0.85 с и 1.55 с (в 1.8 раза).

Вопрос точности выполняемых вычислений остался за рамками эксперимента.

Выводы не делаю, просто чисто информативное сообщение. Каждый для своей программы (что важнее — скорость или точность/надежность) делает их сам. (Лично я для своих в основном научных расчетов вопрос давно решил в пользу точности.)

Интересно было бы сравнить результаты для других компиляторов.

***Конструктивная*** критика принимается с благодарностью.

Вот код (суть по сути :) неважна, специально старался как можно больше использовать типы с плавающей точкой).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//typedef float fptype;
typedef double fptype;

template<typename T, typename Func>
requires std::is_floating_point_v<T>
T Simpson(T a, T b, T eps, Func&& f)
{
    T N = 4.;
    T sum1 = 0., sum2 = 0.;
    T x, h, index1, index2, func;
    unsigned int i;
    do {
        h = (b-a)/N;
        sum1 = sum2 = -(f(a)+f(b));
        index1 = index2 = 4.;
        i = 0;
        for(x = a; x <= b+h/2.; x+=h) {
            sum1 +=  (index1 = T{6.}-index1)*(func=f(x));
            if (i++%2==0) {
                sum2 += (index2 = T{6.}-index2)*func;
            };
        };
        if (fabs((sum1-T{2.}*sum2)/sum1)<=eps)
            return (h*sum1)/T{3.}+h*(T{2.}*sum2-sum1)/T{45.};
        else N*= T{2.};
    } while(N < (1<<20));
    return (h*sum1)/T{3.};
};

fptype f(fptype x)
{
    fptype s = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) s += sin(x*i)*(cos(x*i)-sin(x*i));
    fptype p = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) p *= pow(abs(log(abs(x)+fptype(0.1))),fptype(1.)/(fptype(1.)+i));
    p += s;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) p /= x+fptype(0.2);
    return p + s;
}
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    cout << Simpson(fptype(0),fptype(100),fptype(1e-18),f);
}
```

Comment: Последовательное суммирование - не самый показательный пример. Решение СЛАУ Зейделем лучше. Потому что там голая арифметика, метод итеративный (то есть неважно что float сильнее ошибается - куда-нибудь да сойдемся).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я не хочу с матрицами. Потому что тогда встанет вопрос о размещении в кэше (`float` меньше, и матрица с ним, допустим, полностью в кэше, а с `double` нет или т.п. вопросы). Кроме того, плавающая точка — это не только арифметика.